# why does checkbox stops working when ever i use addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html

when ever i use `addEventListener` my check box stops working i tried removing every code but when i add this code my checkbox stops working
this is my event listener

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

my document has `innerhtml` before it and i wanted to get the selected items id
this is the `innerhtml`

```
document.innerHTML += "<div class='product-container'><div class='course'><div class='course-preview'><img class='product-image' src="+productimageUrl+"></div><div class='course-info'><div class='progress-container'><h6>OnSale: "+ productsale +"</h6><h6>Featured: "+productfeatured +"</h6><h6>soldOut: "+ productsoldout +"</h6></div><h2>"+ productname +" "+ productprice +" </h2><h4>"+productcategory+", "+productsubcategory+"</h6><h4>"+ productamount +"</h4><h6>PRODUCT ID:</h6><h5>"+ productid +"</h5><button id='editbutton' class='btn'>Edit Product</button></div></div></div>"
```

whenever i use this code this code it stops working in case you want document this is my document

```
const document = document.getElementById("main-page");
```

Comment: You prevent the default behavior (checkbox gets ticked) from happening by using e.PreventDefault(). Maybe describe what you want to achieve.

Comment: `innerHTML` in `document` is a custom property, it has no native representation.

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` cancels the default behavior. 

The default behavior of click event for a checkbox is also cancelled by it because onclick it reads the state of **checked** `true | false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`e.preventDefault();` prevents any action that would've taken place when clicking.

If you want to preventDefault() only when you're *not* clicking on a checkbox, test if the target object is or not an input.

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if(e.target.tagName != "INPUT") {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```